# Custom View Engine for Razor View Helix-type default paths

Tags: mvc, helix, razor

Has anyone been able to make a habitat-compatible razor view engine?

Basically I'd like something that can dynamically search

```
"~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
"~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
"~/Views/{<Relative folder name>}/{0}.cshtml"
```

For example if my project is Sitecore.Foundation.Test and I have:

```
~/Views/Test/Test.cshtml
~/Views/Test/_Test.cshtml
```

And then Test.cshtml calls RenderPartial("_Test")

The default razor engine doesn't work for this scenario when the "Test.cshtml" is added as a view rendering, and the page has a controller rendering with a different controller name.

Comment: See also: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/sitecore-mvc-independent-experience-editor-views/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create your custom View Engine to resolve relative paths based on the assembly name.

So, following this guide: https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location

You can add a path like that:

```
"~/Views/%feature/{0}.cshtml"
```

And override the following methods:

```
protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        var featureName = controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath.Replace("%feature", featureName));
    }

protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)

protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
```

This will resolve to `~/Views/Sitecore.Foundation.Test/Test.cshtml`

You can play around with index/substring of `.` to get it to just feature name.

Comment: I'm also using RazorGenerator.MsBuild, is it possible to get something to work with that too?

Comment: That would be a separate question @gibbocool